# Program around this while loop not working as expected

Tags: c++

```
int i=0;
while(i == 0){
  if(digitalRead(saveSwitch) == HIGH){
    Serial.print("New coordinates saved \n");
    lat1 = gps.location.lat();
    Serial.print("Latitude");
    Serial.println(lat1);

    lng1 = gps.location.lng();
    Serial.print("Longitude");
    Serial.println(lng1);
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

Why isn't leaving the while loop?

Comment: Is it ever triggering the if() and printing?  If it is, what's outside this code? and does it dump it right back into the while(){}?   Maybe put a Serial.println() after the while(){} to prove you aren't misdiagnosing the unseen code.

Comment: I've printed the value of i and it's 1 after my switch goes high. I even used i++; to see if it increases, but it only increases once and after that it just prints out the lat and lng every time the switch goes high. Edit: nothing outside the while loop gets executed after i is set to 1.

Comment: Then it is getting out of the while loop.  Your problem is in the unseen, surrounding code.

Comment: All right, I'll look into the whole code and tell you what I find by tomorrow.

Comment: If you want `i` to maintain its state outside of the posted code, perhaps you should move the `i=0;` statement outside of its current scope.

Comment: Is that code from the `loop()` function? How many lines is the whole function? Can you add them all if it's beyond 100 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't leaving the while loop?

There's a good chance that the code *is*  leaving the `while` loop, repeatedly.  However, if the code that's shown is in (eg) the `loop()` function, `i` will be reset to 0 each time the function runs, which will cause the `while` loop to start again.

As noted in Dave X's comment, you can move `int i=0;` to a higher scope. Moving it to file scope, for example, will allow it to retain its value through repeated function calls.  For example, if the code shown is in `loop()`, you could put `int i=0;` just before `void loop() {`.

Note, having generically-named variables like `i` declared at a high level is a bad idea, a blunder, a programming faux pas.  An alternative is to leave its declaration within `loop()` but add the `static` keyword so that `i` is allocated only once, rather than being reallocated and reinitialized at each execution of `loop()`.  For example:  `static int i=0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting i=1, you could use a 'break' command to break out of the while loop.  That way you don't need 'i' at all, you can just do 'while(true)'